# How to terminate program upon pressing ESCAPE?

Tags: java

I have tried a lot of things, but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help me make this program exit when I press escape? I don't have much experience with Threads, so that may be one disadvantage I have.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Main implements ActionListener {

    public static boolean start = false;

    public static void Start() {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Choose Action:");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Hello");
            JButton button1 = new JButton("Start");

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                Robot robot = null;
                try {
                    robot = new Robot();
                } catch (AWTException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                start = true;
                System.out.println("Pressed");

                    while(start) {

                           robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
                           try{
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        } 
                        catch(Exception ex) {

                        }
                        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(150);
                        } 
                        catch(Exception ex) {

                        }

                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        } 
                        catch(Exception ex) {

                        }
                        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(150);
                        } 
                        catch(Exception ex) {

                        }

                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        } 
                        catch(Exception ex) {

                        }
                        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(150);
                        } 
                        catch(Exception ex) {

                        }

                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        } 
                        catch(Exception ex) {

                        }
                        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(150);
                        } 
                        catch(Exception ex) {
                    }
                }
              } 
            } );

        JButton button2 = new JButton("Exit");

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                  start = false;
                frame.dispose();
                System.exit(0);
              } 
            } );

        frame.setTitle("Test");
        frame.setSize(350, 100);
        frame.setResizable(false );
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);
        panel.add(label2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    public static void main (String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Start();
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    }
}
```

I am honestly at a loss here. Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Two points of error calling `Thread.sleep` on the EDT, running an infinite loop within an `actionListener`

Comment: I need it to be an infinite loop though (Kind of). I just need a way to break it ONLY when I hit escape.

Comment: You've got no code in all that code you've posted that is in any way related to your problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thread in java which handles all `GUI` events is known as the Event Dispatch Thread or EDT in short. The EDT thus should always be kept free so that it can process and serve all requests. If you are running an infinite loop within an EDT or performing long running tasks such as sleeping all GUI events will be blocked. THE UI will freeze.

In your code you are running an infinite loop within an `actionListener` , so the EDT is trapped within that loop and cannot process other UI events.

If you require such an `infinite loop` functionality, use a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

`SwingWorker` allows you to run long running tasks in a separate background thread keeping the EDT free.

This is the code for the `button1` `actionListener` using a `SwingWorker`. Paste this one and see. The only catch is that it will create a new `SwingWorker` for every click of start button, but you can fix that easily by disabling the button after it is clicked

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()                                  
{                                                                               
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)                                  
    {                                                                           
        SwingWorker<Void, Void> sw = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>()              
        {                                                                       
            @Override                                                           
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception                    
            {                                                                   
                Robot robot = new Robot();                                      
                start = true;                                                   
                System.out.println("Pressed");                                  

                while (start)                                                   
                {                                                               
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);                              
                    Thread.sleep(1);                                            
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);                            
                    Thread.sleep(150);                                          
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);                              
                    Thread.sleep(1);                                            
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);                            
                    Thread.sleep(150);                                          
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);                              
                    Thread.sleep(1);                                            
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);                            
                    Thread.sleep(150);                                          
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);                              
                    Thread.sleep(1);                                            
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);                            
                    Thread.sleep(150);                                          
                }                                                               
                return null;                                                    
            }                                                                   
        };                                                                      
        sw.execute();                                                           
    }                                                                           
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the `Robot` us for, but the simplest way to capture an key event and respond to it is through the [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API

GUI programming is about responding to events that may occur at any time and any sequence, generally events are delivered to you via the use of an observer pattern.  That is, you register interest and when the event occurs, you are notified, you don't need to do anything else.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ClickOfDeath {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClickOfDeath();
    }

    private KeyTask keyTask;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public ClickOfDeath() {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(
                        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JPanel buttons = new JPanel();

                final JButton type = new JButton("Start");
                type.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        textArea.requestFocusInWindow();
                        if (keyTask == null) {
                            type.setText("Stop");
                            keyTask = new KeyTask();
                            new Thread(keyTask).start();
                        } else {
                            keyTask.stop();
                            keyTask = null;
                            type.setText("Start");
                        }
                    }

                });

                JButton close = new JButton(new CloseAction());
                InputMap im = close.getInputMap(JButton.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
                ActionMap am = close.getActionMap();

                im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "escape");
                am.put("escape", new CloseAction());

                buttons.add(type);
                buttons.add(close);

                textArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
                textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                textArea.setLineWrap(true);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
                frame.add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(close);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public static class KeyTask implements Runnable {

        private volatile boolean keepRuning = true;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Robot bot = new Robot();
                bot.setAutoDelay(40);
                while (keepRuning) {
                    bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_S);
                    bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_W);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_I);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_N);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_G);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_I);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_S);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_A);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_W);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_E);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_S);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_O);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_M);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_E);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD);
                    type(bot, KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD);
                }
            } catch (AWTException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void stop() {
            keepRuning = false;
        }

        protected void type(Robot bot, int keyCode) {
            bot.keyPress(keyCode);
            bot.keyRelease(keyCode);
        }

    }

    public class CloseAction extends AbstractAction {

        public CloseAction() {
            putValue(NAME, "Close");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Swing is a single thread environment, that is, the Swing runs in its own thread.  Any actions or operations that block that thread will prevent the Swing from dispatching new events to registered listeners.

Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: The Robot was used in my program because it simulates hitting a key on the keyboard. For example, robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W) would be like me hitting the 'w' key. It's part of the program I am writing. Also thanks for your help.

Comment: I've updated the example to include a robot thread...